# highlighting intersections

Tags: materials, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I'm not sure the best way to explain this, but I want a material to mix into an emission shader along the edge where it intersects with another object. This video is a good example:[link](https://youtu.be/vsae7C1TgZc?t=300)

**edit:** I want to do be able to do this in realtime (eevee), thought I'd add it here rather than just having it in the tags.

**edit:** [image: thin]

**edit:** I also want to be able to achieve this in eevee with this same method. this is done in cycles:

[image: cycles]

and this is eevee:

[image: eevee]

Answer (score 3):

I just followed the method in that link:

1. you can use add shader in the end but results were not good so I used a mix of 50/50
2. you can use a light path node with out put of is camera ray to get rid of shadows.

[image]

- works in eevee too but you should enable ambient occlusion + make the shader show transparency + adjust the color ramp. if adjusting color ramp is hard add a math node with power before it.

[image]
eevee setup

Comment: thank you for the input, and i'm sorry, i should've mentioned that i wanted to do this in eevee in the post as well, instead of just leaving it in the tags. the ambient occlusion node doesn't work in eevee like it does in cycles.

Comment: works in eevee too but you should enable ambient occlusion + make the shader show transparency + adjust the color ramp. if adjusting color ramp is hard add a math node with power before it.

Comment: could you show me a node example for using it in eevee? i know it needs ambient occlusion under render settings enabled for it to work, but tweaking with math nodes and color ramps still cause it to glitch out at less than 90 degree view angles (depending on the math function). this was when i tested it on a plane with an object intersecting it (material was applied on the plane). will get on pc in about 12 hours

Comment: Edited my answer. better results need more adjusting but I leave that to you.

Comment: I've editted my post, with a new image with the material having the exact same nodes and values, and settings enabled, but some parts seem thinner than others. I have tweaked the values around, but the intersecting area seems to always be thinner.

Comment: Play with ambient factor. Also scale is important. Adjust the last mix to 20/80. Spend some time with your shader and adjust it. If I handhold you all the way you will never learn.